# В каком предложении обстоятельство выражено существительным

Tags: синтаксис, морфология

Поезд отошел вечером.

Оловом поблескивали залитые дождем дороги.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В каком предложении обстоятельство выражено существительным?

Во втором: *поблёскивали (как?) -- **оловом**.*

**P.S.**

В первом предложении ***вечером*** -- наречие.